# Problem with creating array using arrays

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays , $array1 & $array2. I want to create new array such that its `key value` is values of array1 and `values` are values of array2. Is it possible..

I used following approach to create this new array named **$inputs**. Is this correct?

```
$inputs=array();
$array1=array("3","4","6");
$array2=array("a","b","c");
$inputs=array_fill("$array1",count($array1),$array2);
print_r($inputs);
```

Comment: Just test it. Additionally array_combine() is what you're looking for probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_combine`.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-combine.php

```
$inputs = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I read your question correctly, you can use [`array_combine()` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/array-combine)

```
$array1 = array("3","4","6");
$array2 = array("a","b","c");
$inputs = array_combine($array2, $array1); # keys, values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$inputs=array();
$array1=array("3","4","6");
$array2=array("a","b","c");
$inputs=array_combine($array1,$array2);
print_r($inputs);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/6fTXCZa5
use php array_combine function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php